# How to add E-Mail address for system account in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I am working with workflows and trying to send e-mails.

On the workflow page I got an error message:

`The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient.`

User is system account. So I think that I need to set e-mail address of system account.

1. Does any one know how to set e-mail address for system account ?
2. Does any one have a better idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post this type of question on [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) as it is unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to add an email in system account.

1. If you are usin gactive directory user to login in sharepoint as system account then you have to mention his/her email address in the Active directory.
2. If you are using local user as a system account then follow this steps.

Click on drop down of System Account -> Click on My Settings -> Click on Edit Item and Update it with valid email address.

Let me know the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

In your server move to the following location

Start --> Administrative Tools --> Active Directory Users and Computers

There you can find the list of users. You can also find the administrator there.
Now right click the administrator and choose properties and ad your email